# Como passar o valor de uma variável de uma classe local para outra classe (fora do seu escopo e com visibilidade pública)?

Tags: java, android, escopo-de-variáveis

Boa noite. Estou com bastante dificuldade de utilizar o valor de uma variável em uma classe local e passá-la para outra classe que irá ser carregada na intent. O valor da string está saindo nula e dá erro na aplicação. Sou iniciante, já pesquisei bastante e ainda não consegui descobrir uma forma de passar esse valor. Gostaria que me ajudassem. Desde já agradeço.

```
public class Carro extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView lvCarrinhoItems;
Button bFinalizar;
String url2 = "";
String parametros2 = "";
String insertUrl = "http://localhost/registrar.php";
RequestQueue requestQueue;
String result = "";
public static String idOrder = "", dta = "";
public static MeuPedido meuPedido;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.shopping_carrinho);

    lvCarrinhoItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.tela5lv);

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();

    final Carrinhos carrinhos = CarrinhoHelper.getCarrinhos();
    final TextView tvTotalPrice = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvsoma);
    final TextView tvObspedido = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etobscar);
    tvTotalPrice.setText((Bandeja.MOEDA+String.valueOf(carrinhos.getTotalPrice().setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP))).replace(".",","));

    final TCartItemAdapter tcartItemAdapter = new TCartItemAdapter(this);
    tcartItemAdapter.updateCartItems(getCarrinhoItems(carrinhos));


            lvCarrinhoItems.setAdapter(tcartItemAdapter);

            bFinalizar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);


            bFinalizar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder alerta = new AlertDialog.Builder(Carro.this);
                    alerta.setTitle("Confirmação de pedido");
                    alerta

                            .setIcon(R.drawable.service)
                            .setMessage("Deseja confirmar o seu pedido?")
                            .setCancelable(false)
                            .setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {


                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                }
                            })
                            .setPositiveButton("Sim", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

                                    ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
                                            getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                                    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();


                                    pref = getSharedPreferences("login.conf", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                                    final String idcliente = pref.getString("idusuario", null);
                                    final String idrestaurante = CarrinhoHelper.getIdResta();
                                    final String valorpedido = String.valueOf(carrinhos.getTotalPrice());
                                    final String obspedido = tvObspedido.getText().toString();
                                    if (idcliente == null){
                                        Intent intent = new Intent(Carro.this, A2_1semlogin.class);
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                    }else


                                    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {

                                        url2 = "http://localhost/registrarpedido.php";


                                        parametros2 = "idcliente=" + idcliente + "&idrestaurante=" + idrestaurante + "&valorpedido=" + valorpedido + "&obspedido=" + obspedido;

                                        new SolicitaDados2().execute(url2);

                                    } else {
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Por favor, verifique sua conexão", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }

                                    Log.d("DadosRet2", parametros2);
                                    Log.d("DadosRet2", idcliente + ", " + idrestaurante + ", " + valorpedido + ", " + obspedido);



                                     class MyAsyncTaskresources extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


                                        @Override
                                        protected void onPreExecute() {



                                        }
                                        @Override
                                        protected String  doInBackground(String... params) {


                                            InputStream isr = null;

                                            try{
                                                String URL=params[0];
                                                java.net.URL url = new URL( URL);
                                                URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
                                                isr  = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

                                            }

                                            catch(Exception e){



                                            }

                                            try{

                                                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(isr,"iso-8859-1"),8);

                                                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                                                String line = null;

                                                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                                                    sb.append(line + "\n");

                                                }


                                                isr.close();

                                                result=sb.toString();

                                                String s = "";

                                                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                                                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {

                                                    final  JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                                    s = s + "login info : " + json.getString("idOrder") + " " + json.getString("idcliente") + " " + json.getString("idrestaurante") + " " + json.getString("data");


    **STRING QUE DESEJO ACESSAR = idOrder** 

                                                    idOrder = json.getString("idOrder");
                                                    dta = json.getString("data");


                                                    List<CarrinhoItem> carrinhoItems = new ArrayList<CarrinhoItem>();
                                                    Log.d(TAG, "Current shopping cart: " + carrinhos);

                                                    Map<TSaleable, Integer> itemMap = carrinhos.getItemWithQuantity();


                                                    for (Map.Entry<TSaleable, Integer> entry : itemMap.entrySet()) {

                                                        final CarrinhoItem carrinhoItem = new CarrinhoItem();
                                                        carrinhoItem.setBandeja((Bandeja) entry.getKey());
                                                        carrinhoItem.setQuantidade(entry.getValue());
                                                        carrinhoItems.add(carrinhoItem);


                                                        final String idcomida = carrinhoItem.getBandeja().getIdcomida();
                                                        final String quantidade = carrinhoItem.getBandeja().getQuantidade();
                                                        final BigDecimal valorunit = carrinhoItem.getBandeja().getPreco();
                                                        final String adicional = carrinhoItem.getBandeja().getAdicional();
                                                        final String obsproduto = carrinhoItem.getBandeja().getObsproduto();


                                                        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, insertUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                                                            @Override
                                                            public void onResponse(String response) {

                                                                System.out.println(response.toString());
                                                            }
                                                        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                                                            @Override
                                                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                                                            }
                                                        }) {

                                                            @Override
                                                            public Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {


                                                                Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();

                                                                parameters.put("idOrder",idOrder);
                                                                parameters.put("idcomida", idcomida);
                                                                parameters.put("quantidade", quantidade);
                                                                parameters.put("valorunit", valorunit.toString());
                                                                parameters.put("adicional", adicional);
                                                                parameters.put("obsproduto", obsproduto);

                                                               final MeuPedido meupedido = new MeuPedido();
                                                                String novaId = idOrder;

                                                                meupedido.setmPedido(novaId);

                                                                return parameters;

                                                            }

                                                        };
                                                        requestQueue.add(request);

                                                    }

                                                    break;
                                                }

                                            }

                                            catch(Exception e){

                                                Log.e("log_tag", "Error  converting result " + e.toString());

                                            }

                                            return null;

                                        }

                                    }

                                    new MyAsyncTaskresources().execute("http://localhost/sel.php?idcliente="+idcliente+"&idrestaurante=" +idrestaurante);

                                }

                            });

                    AlertDialog alertaDialog = alerta.create();
                    alertaDialog.show();
                }
            });

}


public static final List<CarrinhoItem> getCarrinhoItems(Carrinhos carrinhos) {
    List<CarrinhoItem> carrinhoItems = new ArrayList<CarrinhoItem>();
    Log.d(TAG, "Current shopping cart: " + carrinhos);

    Map<TSaleable, Integer> itemMap = carrinhos.getItemWithQuantity();

    for (Map.Entry<TSaleable, Integer> entry : itemMap.entrySet()) {
       final CarrinhoItem carrinhoItem = new CarrinhoItem();
        carrinhoItem.setBandeja((Bandeja) entry.getKey());
        carrinhoItem.setQuantidade(entry.getValue());
        carrinhoItems.add(carrinhoItem);

        final String comida = carrinhoItem.getBandeja().getComida();
        final String adicional = carrinhoItem.getBandeja().getAdicional();
        final String quantidade =  carrinhoItem.getBandeja().getQuantidade();
        final BigDecimal valor = carrinhoItem.getBandeja().getPreco();

    }

        return carrinhoItems;
    }


private class SolicitaDados2 extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        return Conexao.postDados(urls[0], parametros2);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String resultado) {

         if (resultado.contains("pedido_ok")) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Registro efetuado com sucesso", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

             Intent intent = new Intent(Carro.this, Anotafiscal.class);


**  LOCAL ONDE DESEJO INSERIR A STRING**

             String  hjhj = idOrder ;
             intent.putExtra("iddopedido",hjhj);

             startActivity(intent);
             finish();


        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ocorreu um erro no cadastro", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

}



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

Podes fazer algo como isto na **primeira classe**.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SegundaClasse.class);
intent.putExtra("ID da Variavel", valorParaEnviar);
startActivity(intent);
```

Na **outra class**,

```
String receberValor = getIntent().getStringExtra("ID da Variavel");
```

Espero ter ajudado